# Is it possible restore ipfs file by hash?

Tags: ipfs

I have hash of ipfs file, node with this file not work. But I need some how restore this file.

Can I some how restore file from hash?

Answer (score 0):

You can download data from IPFS as long as there is at least one node providing it.

If the data was only at one node, and you shut it down, you won't be able to get the data until the node gets online again or someone else with the same data adds it to IPFS and announces it to DHT.

To get a list of nodes providing data for specific hash:

```
ipfs dht findprovs QmbWqxBEKC3P8tqsKc98xmWNzrzDtRLMiMPL8wBuTGsMnR
```

If you want to download data from IPFS but can't run local node try downloading it from one of [public gateways](https://ipfs.github.io/public-gateway-checker/).